# getBackgroundPage gives me "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get an html code from background.html to content.js.

I tried:

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage( function() {
    console.log("This is just to check if the function works");
});
```

My manifest file:

```
"background": {
    //"scripts": ["background.js"],
    "page": "background.html",
    "persistent": false
},
```

I'm getting an error: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" on line where "chrome.extension" is.

Comment: "permissions": ["background"] ...and I think you need persistent to TRUE

Comment: i got permissions set, and it didn't help when i changed persistent to  true

Comment: @vux777 The background permission is completely unrelated.

Comment: awww ...my bad... I thought because "undefined" that it's about permission, just now I've read what background permission acutally does